# Как отправить фотографию и к ней подпись. (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Как отправить фотографию и к ней подпись.  (aiogram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы отправить фотографию необходимо использовать функцию `send_photo()`, а для того что бы добавить к ней текст используйте параметр функции `caption`:

```
from aiogram import Bot, types

# Получаем объект класса InputFile для фотографии
photo = types.InputFile('path_to_photo.jpg')

# Отправляем фотографию и текст с помощью метода send_photo
bot.send_photo(chat_id='CHAT_ID', photo=photo, caption='Текст к фотографии')
```